# Adding whitespace in a Javascript document.write

Tags: javascript, html, whitespace, document.write

So I'm currently creating a dynamic table using some JavaScript and a set of objects.  I need to add in some white space between the two but one space isn't enough, I need to have it almost tabbed out.  What would be the best way to do this?  Here is my code for it so far:

```
var sections = {

   p1 : {sname: "Dynamic Table", mscore: 20},
   p2 : {sname: "IntelliJ Usage", mscore: 10},
   p3 : {sname: "Calender Control", mscore: 30},
   p4 : {sname: "Active Form", mscore: 20},
   p5 : {sname: "Object Database", mscore: 20}
};

document.write(Object.keys(sections).reduce(function(s, p, i) {
   var o = sections[p];
   return s + (i>0?'<br><br><br><br>':'') + o.sname + '  ' + o.mscore + ' ' }, '')
);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to add whitespace to the DOM, try using a nonbreaking space

```
'&nbsp;'
```

instead of

```
' '
```

These nonbreaking spaces can be chained.

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

would force two spaces to be displayed on the page.

Answer (score 4):

You could `return s + "<div class='whatever'>" + o.sname + ' ' + o.mscore + "</div>"` and use CSS to set the whitespace.

```js
var sections = {

   p1 : {sname: "Dynamic Table", mscore: 20},
   p2 : {sname: "IntelliJ Usage", mscore: 10},
   p3 : {sname: "Calender Control", mscore: 30},
   p4 : {sname: "Active Form", mscore: 20},
   p5 : {sname: "Object Database", mscore: 20}
};

document.write(Object.keys(sections).reduce(function(s, p, i) {
   var o = sections[p];
   return s + "<div class='whatever'>" + o.sname + '  ' + o.mscore + "</div>" }, '')
);
```

```css
div.whatever { padding-bottom: 5em; }
```

**update** Using a table:

```js
var sections = {

   p1 : {sname: "Dynamic Table", mscore: 20},
   p2 : {sname: "IntelliJ Usage", mscore: 10},
   p3 : {sname: "Calender Control", mscore: 30},
   p4 : {sname: "Active Form", mscore: 20},
   p5 : {sname: "Object Database", mscore: 20}
};

document.write("<table>" + Object.keys(sections).reduce(function(s, p, i) {
   var o = sections[p];
   return s + "<tr><td>" + o.sname + '</td><td>' + o.mscore + "</td></tr>" }, '')
+ "</table>");
```

```css
td { padding-bottom: 2em }
```

Comment: how would I go about adding whitespace inbetween the two scores in order for it to be equal (no out of alignment issues) ?

Comment: You would need to use a monospaced font, calculate the maximum string length for `o.sname` and pad the rest. But it's far easier to use a `<table>` and let the browser do all that for you. I've updated the answer with an example.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to control the spacing would be through CSS. Wrap each one in a class and style it according to taste.

An alternative is to use a couple non-breaking spaces `&nbsp;`.

As such: `return s + (i>0?'<br><br><br><br>':'') + o.sname + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + o.mscore + ' ' }, '')`

Answer (score 3):

fastest solution is to wrap all your sections in a `<pre></pre>` tag.

in your code:

```
var sections = {

   p1 : {sname: "Dynamic Table", mscore: 20},
   p2 : {sname: "IntelliJ Usage", mscore: 10},
   p3 : {sname: "Calender Control", mscore: 30},
   p4 : {sname: "Active Form", mscore: 20},
   p5 : {sname: "Object Database", mscore: 20}
};

document.write("<pre>"); //<--here
document.write(Object.keys(sections).reduce(function(s, p, i) {
   var o = sections[p];
   return s + (i>0?'<br><br><br><br>':'') + o.sname + '  ' + o.mscore + ' ' }, '')
);
document.write("</pre>"); //<--...and here
```

a better solution would be to use CSS

```
.wrapper-class {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use four or five non-breaking spaces to add a tab. The code will look like this `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`

If you need to use tabs throughout something you are displaying, consider formatting options offered by CSS.

Answer (score 0):

To add space in DOM you have to use two 'nbsp;' to print one space like this

```
document.write('nbsp;');
document.write('nbsp;');
```

this will print only one space that I found during one of my pattern problem.